# In Russian, how do you idiomatically say "a one-to-one mix"?

Tags: выражения

> **A one-to-one mix** of coffee and milk, with foam on top.

In conversation, I wanted to express this idea in Russian. I'm looking for the Russian equivalent of "a one-to-one mix (of ...)" in the sense of "**half** coffee (and) **half** milk".

Answer (score 14):

**Кофе пополам с молоком, с пенкой.**

> И пил солдат из медной кружки
>
> Вино с печалью пополам.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5k-3PhdAkw

Comment: Браво, Леночка!

Answer (score 4):

**Кофе с молоком пОровну / один к одному / половина на половину**

When you only need to specify HOW you want it while WHAT you want ([**`кофе с молоком`**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC) - *which is a conventional designation of the drink*) is already clear, it can be phrased as

**Поровну кофе и молока / Кофе и молока половина на половину**

By itself without specifying the type of substance **`a one-to-one mix`** can be expressed as **`сочетание один к одному`** and in the form of an adverbial **`as a one-to-one mix`** - **`в сочетании/пропорции один к одному`**. But this sounds technical therefore wouldn't be applied to edibles in the context of consumption, mostly to recipes.

Comment: "Половина на наполовину" - очень странная фраза. Как и "кофе и молока наполовину". Добавить к этому акцент, и я скажу, что человек просто не знает, как это выразить по-русски.

Comment: *половина на наполовину* was a typo, and i do have an accent, but indeed **пополам** didn't occur to me

Answer (score 2):

Usually, literally **one-to-one**:

> Один к одному

Sometimes, **fifty-fifty**:

> Пятьдесят на пятьдесят

Or slang variation:

> Писят на писят